# affintity and anti-affinity between pods. ensure webapp connect to local redis cache

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

In the documentation about affinity and anti-affinity rules for kubernetes there is a pratical use case arround a [web application and a local redis cache](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#more-practical-use-cases).

1. The redis deployment has PodAntiAffinity configured to ensure the scheduler does not co-locate replicas on a single node.
2. The webapplication deployment has a pod affinity to ensure the app is scheduled with the pod that has label store (Redis).

To connect to the redis from the webapp we would have to define a service.

Question: How are we sure that the webapp will always use the redis that is co-located on the same node and not another one? If I read the [version compatibility](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#version-compatibility) from Kubernetes v1.2 the **iptables mode** for kube-proxy became the **default**.

Reading the docs about [iptable mode for kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables) it says **by default**, kube-proxy in iptables mode **chooses a backend at random**.

<s>So my answer to the question would be:
**No we can't be sure**. If you want to be sure then put the redis and webapp in one pod?</s>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured in the (redis) Service, but in general it is not recommended:

> Setting `spec.externalTrafficPolicy` to the value `Local` will only proxy requests to local endpoints, never forwarding traffic to other nodes

This is a complex topic, read more here:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/